# SQLDecodeError(err_key=tok.value, djongo.exceptions.SQLDecodeError

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I am working on a project in **Django** with **mongoDB**. my app's name is `app`.

my `models.py`:

```
class myCustomeUser(AbstractUser):
    #id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique="True", blank=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    is_Employee = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_Inspector = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_Industry = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_Admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

class Industry(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(myCustomeUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, related_name='industry_releted_user')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    license = models.IntegerField(null=True, unique=True)
    industry_extrafield = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(myCustomeUser, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    industry = models.ForeignKey(Industry, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    i_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=True)
    gmail = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=False, unique=True)
    rank = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=True)
    employee_varified = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Inspector(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(myCustomeUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='inspector_releted_user')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=True)
    gmail = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=False, unique=True)
    nationalid = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=False, unique=True)
    inspector_extrafield = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Admin(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(myCustomeUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='admin_releted_user')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=True)
    gmail = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=False, unique=True)
    admin_extrafield = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class PrevJob(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    industry = models.ForeignKey(Industry, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    i_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    #name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=True)
    rank = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.employee.name
```

in `settings.py`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'ProjectSurokkhaBetaDB_5',
    }
}
```

Today morning I drop my full database (and create a fully new one) and remove all files inside `app\migrations` (except `__init__.py`). And run `makemigrations`, then I run `migrate`. But after running the `migrate` command it says the following error in the terminal:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, app, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
This version of djongo does not support "NULL, NOT NULL column validation check" fully. Visit https://www.patreon.com/nesdis
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial...This version of djongo does not support "schema validation using CONSTRAINT" fully. Visit https://www.patreon.com/nesdis
 OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name...This version of djongo does not support "COLUMN DROP NOT NULL " fully. Visit https://www.patreon.com/nesdis
This version of djongo does not support "DROP CASCADE" fully. Visit https://www.patreon.com/nesdis
 OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial...This version of djongo does not support "schema validation using KEY" fully. Visit 
https://www.patreon.com/nesdis
This version of djongo does not support "schema validation using REFERENCES" fully. Visit https://www.patreon.com/nesdis
 OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0010_alter_group_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0011_update_proxy_permissions... OK
Not implemented alter command for SQL ALTER TABLE "app_employee" ADD COLUMN "industry_id" int NULL
  Applying app.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\djongo\cursor.py", line 51, in execute
    self.result = Query(
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 783, in __init__
    self._query = self.parse()
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 875, in parse
    raise e
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 856, in parse
    return handler(self, statement)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 888, in _alter
    query = AlterQuery(self.db, self.connection_properties, sm, self._params)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 425, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 84, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.parse()
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 435, in parse
    self._add(statement)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 598, in _add
    raise SQLDecodeError(err_key=tok.value,
djongo.exceptions.SQLDecodeError:

        Keyword: int
        Sub SQL: ALTER TABLE "app_employee" ADD COLUMN "industry_id" int NULL
        FAILED SQL: ('ALTER TABLE "app_employee" ADD COLUMN "industry_id" int NULL',)
        Params: ([],)
        Version: 1.3.3

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\djongo\cursor.py", line 59, in execute
    raise db_exe from e
djongo.database.DatabaseError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line   
    utility.execute()
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 231, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 245, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 110, in database_forwards    
    schema_editor.add_field(
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 480, in add_field
    self.execute(sql, params)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 142, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\djongo\cursor.py", line 59, in execute
    raise db_exe from e
django.db.utils.DatabaseError
```

But here the most interesting part is, when I shift from `mongoDB` into **Django**'s default `sqlite3`, there is no error and all are working smoothly with the same code. So maybe there is a problem in using `mongoDB`.

`mongoDB` to `sqlite3` shifting in `settings.py` code:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

I have never faced this type of weird problem before. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you add SQL to migration manually

Comment: No, I didn't add that kind of things

Comment: what version of djongo do you use and what version of sqlparse

Comment: `djongo` version is 1.3.3 and the `sqlparse` version maybe 0.2.4

Comment: maybe? pip freeze your requirements and find out

Comment: yeah, it says `sqlparse==0.2.4`

Comment: it also shows and warning when I run **pip freeze**:
`WARNING: Could not generate requirement for distribution -ip 20.2.3 (g:\python\lib\site-packages): Parse error at 
"'-ip==20.'": Expected W:(abcd...)`

Comment: https://github.com/nesdis/djongo/issues/505